# Center two Text widgets inside the container

Tags: flutter, layout, flutter-layout

I'm a total noob in flutter, so I have a little problem.

I want to center two textblocks (like on a screenshot)
[image]

I have a structure like this:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Hello",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                Text("World",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))
              ],
            ),
            height: 256,
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

But the actually result I see is:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you wrap the 2 texts blocks in a row! Replace it by a Column and it will be good! :)

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Hello",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                Text("World",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
              ],
            ),
            height: 256,
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 

Also, I would be grateful if you clarified the magic around axises alignment in this case :)

Comment: You control how a row or column aligns its children using the mainAxisAlignment and crossAxisAlignment properties. For a row, the main axis runs horizontally and the cross axis runs vertically. For a column, the main axis runs vertically and the cross axis runs horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ListView(
        children: [
          Container(
      child: Center(
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text("Hello",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue)),
                Text("World",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue))
              ],
            ),
            height: 256,
            color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```